# ASP.NET MVC 5 Custom Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I was searching for a resource to learn about new ASP.NET MVC 5 Authentication Filters. Actually what I want is to know how to use Authentication Filters in real world scenarios such as using third party authentication providers (Facebook, Twitter, etc) or custom authentication providers. I searched through the internet and was unable to find something in more detail.

Can you suggest me where to find more details on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pluralsight has a MVC5 course including OWIN and KATANA which may be useful. It's not a free service but you can get a free trial to access the presentation.

Answer (score 2):

I've actually implemented a [customer authentication in ASP.NET MVC](http://nefcanto.com/custom-asp-net-mvc-authentication-and-authorization).

The basics are simple:

1. For each request coming to the server, you should understand whether the resource is private or public. This is done with attributes in MVC.
2. For each private request, you should see if the HTTP request has an authentication ticket or not. It's usually a cookie.
3. If user does have that ticket, then server the resource. Otherwise, redirect user to login page.

Comment: That example isn't MVC5, I think Janaka is asking about authentication using OWIN rather than authorisation attributes

Comment: He has also asked about *custom authentication providers*. He should design a simple authentication mechanism, to understand the basics.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati Thank you very much for the answer. But I'm specifically looking for an example related to MVC 5. Or else can you extend this answer to use Authentication Filters?